# Python Selenium, find_element_by_id, but id changes

Tags: python, string, selenium, methods

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
text = 'buttton527231'
driver.find_element_by_id(text).click()
```

The number of the button changes (`buttton527231`, `button527273`, `button527283`, `button527287`, `button******` etc).

Is there some string method or something, or I have to bruteforce 500 000 buttons...?

Comment: Was the issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'buttons text')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case use xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'buttton')]")
```

Your element may me not `button`, if it's differentput in in the beginning, for example: `//span[contains(text(),'buttton')]`